# get payment method in the success page Magento 2 programmatically

Tags: magento2, order-success-page

How can I display the payment method in the success page using a code?
If anyone can help me, it would be great. Thankyou.

Comment: What is the exact magento 2 version you are using?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I am using Magento ver. 2.1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy the success.phtml from:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/success.phtml

to your theme location:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

Now add the following code to your success.phtml

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();       
$payment = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId())->getPayment();
echo $paymentMethodTitle = $payment->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
?>
```

You can also create one block which extends Success block and then create one method which should return the above code.

***Note: Use of Objectmanager directly in phtml file is not a good practice. you need to create block and adjust those according to your requirement.***

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above using the object manager is the incorrect way to achieve this in Magento 2. To achieve this you need to create a module:

> MyModule/CustomerPaymentType

(Module can we whatever you want) You then need to extend the **\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success** block inside of your own module and for consistency add it to:

> MyModule/CustomerPaymentType/Block/Checkout/Onepage/Success.php

You then add the dependancies to this. Here is an example of the extended block:

```
<?php

namespace MyModule\CustomerPaymentType\Block\Checkout\Onepage;

class Success
extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    protected $order;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order
    ) {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function getOrder(){
       $orderTitle = $this->order->getTitle();
    }
}
```

Then inside of your:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/success.phtml

You can now call **$block->getOrder()**

If you get:

> Type Error occurred when creating object: MyModule/CustomerPaymentType\Block\Checkout\Onepage\Success\Interceptor

Don't forget to clear your **Generated folder**